# SwiftUI: What are the differences between Image and UIImage?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I realize they are different structs, but when should one be used over another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UIImage` is a `UIKit` element it's created to be assigned to an `UIImageView`

`Image` is a `SwiftUI` element in the new framework  released in IOS 13

You should avoid using `UIKit` elemnts in `SwiftUI` as possible , it's like using objective c code in swift which doesn't make sense of releasing a new language

Comment: What should we use instead of UIImage? or can we openly migrate to Image from UIImage?

Answer (score 2):

To be more precise, Image is a *struct* meant to be used with SwiftUI, and UIImage is a *class* meant to be used with UIKit. If you are programming in SwiftUI, you want to be using Image, unless there is some missing functionality, in which case you might need to wrap a UIImage in a UIViewRepresentable.