# Display base64 encoded image without UIImage

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I have a `base64` encoded image stored as a `String`. (State variable because I want to update the image periodically.) I want to use the `Image()` class (Not `UIImage`) to display this image. How do I convert the `base64` image such that it is acceptable to `Image()`?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View
{   
    @State var img_base64:String = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBD [...]"
    
    var body: some View
    {        
            Image() // TODO: How to display img_base64 here? 
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 3):

SwiftUI's `Image` is a view (like `UIImagaView`), and `UIImage` is a data, so you can use

```
Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: Data(base64Encoded: "<your string here>") ?? Data())!)
```

or

```
if let uiImage = UIImage(data: Data(base64Encoded: "<your string here>") ?? Data()) {
    Image(uiImage: uiImage)
}
```

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/60732521/2926577 , UIImage should be avoided in SwiftUI because " it's like using objective c code in swift which doesn't make sense of releasing a new language". Is this accurate? If yes, is there a way to parse base64 directly to Image() omitting UIImage?